# What is the equivalent request of python with curl -d command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests

I am having difficulty finding the python request equivalent to the curl command which send the data in the body as JSON.

The curl command looks like

```
curl -X POST -d '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}' http://localhost:8080/myapi
```

With the CURL request, Server(python) gets the data in requset.form like below

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}', '')])
```

But when sending the same post request like using request module of python

```
response = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/myapi", data=json.dumps({
    "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"))
```

From the server-side, I see the content like

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')]) and its type is : <class 'werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict
```

I am a bit confused about why the request using requests.post having different content at server side compared to using curl request, can someone please help to understand and possible solutions

---

*The issue has solved by adding 'Content-Type:application/json' in both curl and the request made from the request module. Also, I used to check the data in request.form but realized that it is working when I use the request.data, new to python so have missed this, thank you.*

Comment: Your code isn't syntactically valid and those two outputs seem to be the same, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, I am sorry it was a copy-paste error, updated the correct one, thanks

Comment: What happens if you set the correct `Content-Type` header in curl?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, When I set the -H "Content-Type:application/json" I did not receive any data it seems at the server-side

data :  ImmutableMultiDict([])  and type is :  <class 
 werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict'>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just sending the dictionary instead of stringified json?

`r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"})`

running this through the httpbin test server and running your curl statement yield identical responses (with the exception of the user agent.